# How to import external script with parameters in angular.json?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to integrate [pace-js](https://github.com/CodeByZach/pace) to my angular project.
I have added `pace-theme-default.min.css` to `styles` array in `angular.json` and `node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js` to `scripts` array.
All work fine. But I need to pass some custom options to pace script. On script tag the options can be putted like below:

```
<script data-pace-options='{ "ajax": false }' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pace-js@latest/pace.min.js"></script>
```

But how to pass the options in `angular.json`?

Comment: Could you solve it : )

Comment: Nope. Kept it in index.html.